# Synthetic Division with mods

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$x^4+x+1$/
$2x^2$+1

In $F_5$ (means mod 5)

I said let the leading coefficient be 2.
Since $3$ $*$ $2$ - $5$ $*$ $1$ $=$ $1$, choose 3 to multiply

$3$($2x^2$ $+$ $1$)= $x^2$ + $3$ (this is using mod 5)

$3$($x^4$ $+$ $x$ $+$ $1$) $=$ $3x^4$ $+$ $3x$ $+$ $3$ (this is using mod 5)

I said let $-3$ be the root since $x^2$ $+$ $3$

Then I did sythetic division using the root $-3$.

My question is can the root be $-3$? I know it would be if it was $x+3$ but this is $x^2+3$.